# CSS background image height automatically getting cropped

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
.bg-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Here is the CSS code I use to set background-image for a div. The issue I'm facing is that the image height automatically get cropped on reaching a specific screen width (device size). How can I solve this?

Comment: There's no `background-image` property set. Please include a [mre], with HTML in addition to the CSS. You can use an image from a placeholder or dummy image service. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar).

Comment: I set background-image on html       as follow                                                            <div style="background-image: url(assets/img/slide-new8.jpg)">                                <!-- contents -->                                                                                                       <div>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `background-size: contain;` instead. But in this case, you will have empty space either from the top and bottom or from left and right, depending on the screen resolution if the image container is responsive and the image aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your background image to take as much as possible of space without been cropped you can use this like Merianos stated :

```
.bg-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

But if you need to specify the exact width and height you can use the same property with percentage or pixels.

```
    .bg-image {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: 100px 100px;
    }
```